# firebase.auth().CurrentUser.uid is giving null after successful login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have made use of firebase login. It is logging in successfully. I have four pages inside login page profile, sell, buy and about us. When I am retrieving the value of current user's uid in profile and sell page. But i am getting null in buy page why is it so?

**JS**
For userpage

```
function save_user()
      {
     const uid = document.getElementById('user_id');
            const userpwd = document.getElementById('user_pwd');
            const btnregister=document.getElementById('btn-action');
            //btnregister.addEventListener('click', e=>
            //{
            const email=uid.value;
            const pass=userpwd.value;
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    console.log(error.Message);

});
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user) {
    window.location='userpage.html'; 
  }
});
```

**JS**

for buy page where firebase.auth().currentUser.uid is showing null code

```
var fbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Sell_Products");
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; 
alert(user);    /*Here it's showing null
fbRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var key=snap.key;
    alert('HEllo');
    alert(key);
    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var price = snap.child("price").val();
    var category = snap.child("category").val();
    var description = snap.child("description").val();
    var image = snap.child("image").val();
    $("#ex-table").append("<tr><td><a href=\"auction.html?itemKey="+key+"\"><img src=" + image + "/img></a></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );
});
```

Comment: Please someone help!!! It's urgent

Comment: I've written a [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0) about the best practices for this.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to obtain the loggedin user is the way you're handling your redirect on userPage (with an observer):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user);
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

**Edit:** So you should have something like this:

```
var fbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Sell_Products");

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; 
        alert(user);    //you should have your user here!
        fbRef.on("child_added", snap => {
            var key=snap.key;
            alert('HEllo');
            alert(key);
            var name = snap.child("name").val();
            var price = snap.child("price").val();
            var category = snap.child("category").val();
            var description = snap.child("description").val();
            var image = snap.child("image").val();
            $("#ex-table").append("<tr><td><a href=\"auction.html?itemKey="+key+"\"><img src=" + image + "/img></a></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No user is signed in.');
    }
});
```

Comment: will you please elaborate?

Comment: I've added code based on your original code. By the way, why do you want to obtain the current user there? just to verify if they're logged in?

Comment: Basically i am retrieving that information in one of my web page

Comment: What actually i have faced after posting the question is that sometime i am getting uid as null but when i restart my browser or clean my cache it  is working fine that i am getting uid.Why it is happening?

Comment: On chrome developer tools, check the "Application" tab, then "Local Storage", and there you should have an entry of the logged in user (usually named as "localhost:4200"), clear that. Log in again and test the code, please.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered such problem. Actually, until the auth is not initialized, it cant show some data but when we use `firebase.auth().CurrentUser`, it fetches data even before the auth is initialized. You can set a timeout in the code until the auth is completely initialized.

I used this approach to get the data.

```
const authPromise=()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        console.log(user.email)
    })
}

setTimeout(authPromise,2000)
```