# getRedirectResult is returning null after redirect login

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

`onAuthStateChanged` listener fires correctly but `getRedirectResult` always returns `null`, even after directly using the login button and trying to use different browsers without a session.

```
this.auth.getRedirectResult(authUser => {

      if (authUser) {
      } else {
        fallback();
      }
  });
```

The above snippet is best context I can give but I'm pretty confident I am using it correctly inside my `componentDidMount`.

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same trouble, too.

I realized that whenever `user` is null, it emits `onAuthStateChanged` after the return of `getRedirectResult`(in the normal case, `onAuthStateChanged` comes first).

Therefore, I assume there is the same as resolution as `firebase.auth().currentUser`.
That is to observe on `onAuthStateChanged`.

refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49640188

However, as it is written in the firebase document as follows, this may be a bug.

> By using an observer, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an
>   intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current
>   user. When you use signInWithRedirect, the onAuthStateChanged observer
>   waits until getRedirectResult resolves before triggering.

refs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had imported the firebase scripts while at the same time using npm version. I removed the scripts and everything is working as should. The time delay between redirect and the call to getRedirectResult is still ridiculous though.